# How do I show the up button as an icon next to a caret in the Activity Bar?

Tags: android

I am trying to show my custom icon, located in the res/mipmap folder, as an up button, with a caret (little arrow facing to the left) next to it. I have tried calling `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, along with seemingly every other combination of methods that has the word 'up' in it, to no avail. The activity bar shows a left facing arrow, but no icon.

I have the minimum sdk set to 15, target to 21, and am using the support library. I can get the action bar to display my icon as an up button without the caret by calling `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)`, but there is no caret. I have the application icon set in the manifest for the application element, and have even tried setting the `android:homeAsUpIndicator` property in my action bar's style, which still does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since the target version is 21 and lollipop wont encourage in doing that.

You can use setLogo method but the logo wont be adjacent to the arrow, there will be gap between the arrow and logo.

Check this too:
add getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); after you setSupportActionBar to your toolbar.